# Displaying Frequency Table of Individual Clusters Using TraMiner

Tags: r, sequence, cluster-analysis, traminer

I am currently doing a clustering exercise using TraMiner. I have a frequency table, `df.seq`, that I broke into four clusters using the following code:

```
library(cluster)
df.om <- seqdist(df.seq, method='OM', indel=1, sm='TRATE', with.missing=TRUE)
clusterward <- agnes(df.om, diss=TRUE, method="ward")
df.cl4 <- cutree(clusterward, k=4)
cl4.lab <- factor(df.cl4, labels=paste("Cluster", 1:4))
```

Then, I plot a sequence frequency plot of my four clusters.

```
seqfplot(df.seq, group=cl4.lab, pbarw=FALSE, border=NA, withlegend = FALSE, yaxis = "pct", cpal=palette(rainbow(length(unique(df.new$cart)))))
```

While the `seqfplot` gives a good visual, I would like to see a frequency table for each individual cluster. For example, I can do:

```
seqtab(df.seq)
```

and get the following output:

`Sequence     Frequency     %`

`Item #1      10           30%`

`Item #2      9            25%`

`Item #3      8            20%`

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: To use `table` here, we would need to first represent each sequence with a single value. Moreover, `table`cannot handle the possible weights assigned to the state sequences in object `df.seq`. You would have to use `xtabs` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `by`. I illustrate using the `actcal` data that ships with `TraMineR`

```
library(TraMineR)
data(actcal)
actcal.seq <- seqdef(actcal[,13:24])
seqfplot(actcal.seq, group=actcal$sex)
by(actcal.seq, actcal$sex, seqtab)
```

For your example the command would read

```
by(df.seq, cl4.lab, seqtab)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks Gilbert!